# BlueZ 4.101 with kernel 2.6.37

Tags: bluetooth, linux-kernel, bluetooth-lowenergy, embedded-linux, bluez

I have custom device which is on kernel version 2.6.37. In this I have BlueZ version 4.98. I would like to create own GATT server with BT820 Blue-tooth USB-HCI dongle which need minimum BlueZ 4.101. So I have cross-compiled BlueZ 4.101. I would like to know do I need to back-port kernel also? I don't find any information related to kernel on BlueZ.

Comment: Bluez is a combination of library and kernel components.  4.101 may have a minimum kernel requirement to ensure the kernel module has the right functionality.  2.6 is pretty ancient so I suspect you'll have issues with BLE, but I really don't know.  Also, you're going to have a really hard time finding other people who can provide you with information on such an old set up.

Comment: @TimTisdall Is there any way or documentation to back-port such drivers?

Comment: You could try this:  https://backports.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page  Are you certain that 4.101 doesn't run in 2.6?  You may want to start with just trying to use it and see what happens.  The earliest kernel I used with BLE is 3.4 so I have no idea about 2.6 .

Comment: I try to connect with gatttool and it gives error "l2cap_bind: Invalid argument (22)". So I don't know how to debug it more.

Comment: They changed the address arguments to have one more element to handle BLE, so something in your chain isn't handling that.  You likely do need more update bluez kernel components, but I'm not sure if that's sufficient.  Kernel 3.4 has what's needed for BLE, so you could try backporting that (though, it does have a bug with multiplexing more than one BLE connection).  The L2CAP address having one more argument may require some backport in the kernel too...  I'm not really sure.